# How do I run this node express app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I already have one app running on Heroku just fine which I created a few weeks ago for the first time.

Here is the git repo for the functioning app - https://github.com/Sean-99-04/basic

However when I try to run my newest app, it does not work. It builds fine, but gives an application error when ran.

Here is the git repo for that - https://github.com/Sean-99-04/History-Blog

Also I am runnnig this through GitHub, not through Heroku CLI.

I have been searching online for the last 3 hours for answers and here are some things mentioned which I made sure to unclude:

- Procfile with code "web:node ./server.js"
- package.json with code "script": {"start": "node server.js"}
- In server.js I have process.env.PORT and all other necessary process.env's

I greatly appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

This is the error in logs:

2021-01-11T16:50:16.910561+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the history-blog@1.0.0 start script.

2021-01-11T16:50:16.910689+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2021-01-11T16:50:16.915638+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-01-11T16:50:16.915831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2021-01-11T16:50:16.915958+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-11T16_50_16_911Z-debug.log

2021-01-11T16:50:16.988688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-01-11T16:50:17.025320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-01-11T16:50:17.966848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=history-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=f274158b-5399-49ab-97d9-5a83bb387a13 fwd="95.147.237.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Just edited original comment with error.

Comment: Does there happen to be anything more before that? You could try changing your Procfile to be `web: npm start --loglevel silly` to get more log output.

Comment: To clarify. Are you asking me to **change** `web:node ./server.js` to `web: npm start --loglevel silly` or **add** it?

Comment: Yes, if you can. That would give you a lot more log output.

Comment: Ok so it worked, the issue was apparently this `if ((process.env.NODE_ENV = "development")) {
  require("dotenv").config();
}` in my 'routes' file so now comes my follow up question. NODE_ENV surely should not have been set to "development". So why did it run the code regardless?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the failure was caused by trying to loading dotenv. The reason that happened despite Heroku's default NODE_ENV being `production` is that you're assigning in the check, which returns the string `development`, which is truthy — so it gets loaded.

What you have: `if ((process.env.NODE_ENV = "development")) {`

What you want: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {`

Comment: One problem after another. So unfortunately my prettier extension upon save, adds those parenthesese. I guess I'll figure out how to change that some other time though. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The issue isn't the parenthesis, it's the single `=` instead of `==` or `===`. Prettier added those extra parens to try to make it clearer that you were assigning in the condition rather than checking what `process.env.NODE_ENV` is. [See this issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5591) for details on that.

Comment: Oh my bad I'm small brain haha. Thank you.